# Using a Variable & Loop to Create "onclick" Functions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a for loop to generate onclick functions for each of my 4 links below. Right now it doesn't work at all and I am unsure why?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7WYfF/

```
<p><a href="#" id="link0">Link0</a></p>
<p><a href="#" id="link1">Link1</a></p>
<p><a href="#" id="link2">Link2</a></p>
<p><a href="#" id="link3">Link3</a></p>

<script>
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var temp = "link" + i;

    [temp].onclick = function () { 
        alert("You just clicked link: " + i);
    };
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things. First you need to wrap `i` in a closure to store the value that you want. Second `[temp]` will not select a DOM element, you will need to do that differently.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var temp = "link" + i;

    document.getElementById(temp).onclick = (function(t) {
        return function (e) { 
            alert("You just clicked link: " + t);
        };
    })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

var temp = document.getElementById("link" + i);

temp.onclick = function...

Answer (score 0):

you should use getElementById :

```
document.getElementById("link" + i);
```

also i suggest you use jQuery framework. it's so easy than bare javascript.