# Closures Inside of Loops - Create a link and link function for each element in an array

Tags: javascript

I am working on a JavaScript web app that stores sets (stacks) of flashcards in an array.

Right now I am having an issue with closures inside of loops. I reviewed this example (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15466863/1822824) and attempted to implement something similar but I am receiving an error: "TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(temp)')".

The web app should list all of the sets (stacks) of flashcards as links, when you click on a link it alerts you with the name of the flashcard stack that you clicked on. Everything worked fine until I attempted to add the link part that alerts you.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xmYug/

Below is my code:

```
<p>
<strong>Flashcard Stack Name:</strong>
<input type="text" id="textStackName">
</p>
<p>
<strong>Enter one flashcard per line, seperate the front and back of each flashcard with a comma:</strong><br>
<textarea name="textarea" id="textareaFlashcards" cols="45" rows="15"></textarea> 
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" id="buttonSubmit" value="Submit">
</p>
<div id="allStacks">
</div>

<script>
var funcs = [];

function createfunc(i) {
    var temp = "link" + i;

    return document.getElementById(temp).onclick = function() {
        // Alert the user of the stack name they just clicked on
        alert("Stack name: " + allStacks[i].stackName);
    };
}

/* Constructors */
// Constructs a new stack of flashcards - a stack of flashcards is usually about a single topic such as States & Capitals
function newStackConstructor(stackName) {
    this.stackName = stackName;
    this.stack = new Array();
}

// Constructs a new flashcard - a stack can have an unlimited number of flashcards
function newFlashcardConstructor(flashcardFront, flashcardBack) {
    this.flashcardFront = flashcardFront;
    this.flashcardBack = flashcardBack;
}

// Contains all of the flashcard stacks
var allStacks = new Array();

// SAMPLE DATA //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Make a test stack
allStacks.push(new newStackConstructor("States & Capitals"));

// Test data
allStacks[0].stack.push(new newFlashcardConstructor("Alabama", "Montgomery"));
allStacks[0].stack.push(new newFlashcardConstructor("Alaska", "Juneau"));
allStacks[0].stack.push(new newFlashcardConstructor("Arizona", "Phoenix"));
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

buttonSubmit.onclick = function () { 
    newFlashcardStack();
};

// Make a new flashcard stack
function newFlashcardStack() {
    allStacks.push(new newStackConstructor(textStackName.value));

    var textareaFlashcardsTemp = textareaFlashcards.value;

    // Split flashcards by line break
    var flashcards = textareaFlashcardsTemp.split("\n");

    for (var i = 0; i < flashcards.length; i++) {

        // Split front & back of flashcards by comma
        flashcard = flashcards[i].split(",");

        allStacks[(allStacks.length - 1)].stack.push(new newFlashcardConstructor(flashcard[0], flashcard[1]));
    }

    // Update stack display to display all of the stacks and the new stack
    displayAllStacks();
}

// Display all flashcard stacks
function displayAllStacks() {
    // Clear stack display
    document.getElementById("allStacks").innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < allStacks.length; i++) {
        funcs[i] = createfunc(i);

        document.getElementById("allStacks").innerHTML += '<p><a href="#" id="link' + i + '">' + allStacks[i].stackName + '</a></p>';
    }
}

displayAllStacks();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why your closure in which you assign the click handler returns that handler, and you store all of them in that `funcs` array.

However, with

```
funcs[i] = createfunc(i);
document.getElementById("allStacks").innerHTML += '<p><a href="#" id="link' + i + '">' + allStacks[i].stackName + '</a></p>';
```

you try to create *and assign* the handler function even before you create that element. Yet,

```
document.getElementById("allStacks").innerHTML += '<p><a href="#" id="link' + i + '">' + allStacks[i].stackName + '</a></p>';
funcs[i] = createfunc(i);
```

won't work as well, as by assigning to `innerHTML` you *overwrite* the current DOM and create new links that have not assigned any event handlers any more. Instead, use

```
var display = document.getElementById("allStacks");
display.innerHTML = "";
for (var i=0; i<allStacks.length; i++) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    p.appendChild(a);
    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(allStacks[i].stackName));
    a.href="#";
    // a.id = "link"+i; is not necessary
    var func = (function(i) {
        return function() {
            // Alert the user of the stack name they just clicked on
            alert("Stack name: " + allStacks[i].stackName);
        };
    })(i);
    // funcs[i] = func; if you want that
    a.onclick = func;

    display.appendChild(p);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to go through my code, this really helped!